# How to download original Document with macros while being in Excel Online?

Tags: excel, online, file-download, excel-macro

I open an Excel file with macros in Excel Online, where I (correctly) get the message, the file contains unsupported features. But out of this situation I'm not able to download the original file with macros anymore, only a cleaned version by Excel Online without macros.

Are there any ways to download the original file inside Excel Online? Workaround? Configurations?

[image: Features not supported by the web version will be removed from the saved copy - but why?]

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to download the file from the document library without opening the file in excel online first.  Just click on the ellipses (...) beside the document and go to download.