# How can I download an Excel 365 document that is stored on SharePoint and over 100 MB, without having to install the Excel desktop program?

Tags: excel, download

Someone shared with me a link to an Excel 365 document that is stored on SharePoint and over 100 MB. When I click on that link, I get that message:

> Sorry, we can't open your workbook in Excel Online because it exceeds the 100 MB file size limit.

[image]

How can I download an Excel 365 document that is stored on Sharepoint and over 100 MB, without having to install the Excel desktop program?

Comment: Related [Download excel instead of open from server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/221303/107159), [How to download original Document with macros while being in Excel Online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/268447/107159)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the OneDrive for Business app to store the file locally on your machine:

[Sync SharePoint files and folders](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sync-sharepoint-files-and-folders-87a96948-4dd7-43e4-aca1-53f3e18bea9b)

or you can download the file to store it outside of SharePoint. Use the ellipsis in the document library menu and select the download option to download the file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One can go to one's OneDrive's online page, click on "Shared", find the file and click on the ellipsis button, which give the option to download the file:

[image]